# How to Mock Request object in unit testing asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, request, moq

I am working on an asp.net mvc 3.0 application. In unit testing one of the action method in my controller, I was getting an error.

How to mock: `Request.Params["FieldName"]`

I have included Moq framework, but was not sure how to pass value

Here is my code... Please suggest...

```
 var request = new Mock<System.Web.HttpRequestBase>();

 request
     .SetupGet(x => x.Headers)
     .Returns(
         new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
         {
             {"X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"}
         });

 var context = new Mock<System.Web.HttpContextBase>();

 context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);

 ValidCodeController target = new ValidCodeController();

 target.ControllerContext =
     new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), target);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Params` is a `NameValueCollection` property that can be set-up in a similar way to `Headers`:

```
var requestParams = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "FieldName", "value"}
};

request.SetupGet(x => x.Params).Returns(requestParams);
```

Comment: @Chris..Perfect buddy..Thank you :) Can you Please help me in mocking session too.?

Comment: I might be able to help with that - what do you need to do?

Comment: @Chris..Thanks for response..I need to setup some session variables since the method that uses makes use of session variables which i should be mocking .. For eaxmple : Session["UserName"]="Avinash" some thing like that..

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to mocking the Context and all it's dependencies is to abstract the entire context/Params collection in a separate class, and mock that instead. In many cases this will make it easier, and avoids having to mock a complicated object graph:

Ex:

```
public void MainMethod()
{
   var valueInQuestion = ISomeAbstraction.GetMyValue("FieldName");

}
```

You can now mock the `GetMyValue` method instead.